# Advice on building my first pc with ubuntu

Tags: installation, drivers

I have just started to receive the pieces of my computer, I am planning on using just Ubuntu on this computer. I have ordered an AMD A10 APU, a MSI Motherboard, a Seagate hard-drive, and 4GB of RAM.

I have not ordered a DVD drive. Have I made a fatal mistake?

I have a USB drive prepared to install Ubuntu on my new PC but I am worried about installing necessary drivers that came with my motherboard. How will I load these drivers?

Comment: you can check for certified hardware here http://www.ubuntu.com/certification

Comment: DVD ROM will be future forgotten floppy DD.  You can do whatever you want to do with USB Stick, I am having laptop , and in last 3 yeah hardly used DVD drive thrice that too for installing windows , as previously i didn’t knew how to install it through pen drive.

Answer (score 1):

You can install just fine without a DVD drive. Preparing a bootable USB is simple from any operating system up a USB (there are help guides available on the [download page](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) - about half-way down the page).

The drivers that ship with your motherboard will undoubtedly be for Windows only. In Ubuntu, most of your devices will be covered by the drivers built into the Linux kernel so in the vast majority of cases you don't need *any* additional drivers to run Ubuntu.

You should certainly be able to get it to a point where it's installed and usable, by which point any missing drivers can be downloaded using a network connection.